# How would you say "As a x, I find this y"

Tags: expressions

Sometimes in English, to stress a point, we could say something like "As an English person, I find this funny" when perhaps a joke is about an English person.

Another example could be stressing the point of offense and say "As a person of colour, I find this offensive!".

How would these translate into French? Is there an equivalent expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would translate this using the expression “En tant que”:

> En tant que personne de couleur, je trouve cela/ça offensant
>
> En tant qu'Anglais, je trouve cela/ça drôle.